# Init method undefined objective c

Tags: objective-c

so i wrote this piece of code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        BNRPerson *mikey=[[BNRPerson alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%p", mikey);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In BNRPerson class i defined no init method. So how does init know what to do?

Comment: and to what will it initialize mikey? to a random number? why does this number change with time. thanks for answering

Comment: It will be handled by the base class, whatever that is. `mikey` is a pointer; it's an address in memory, but all you really should care about is it's a unique value representing the object you just allocated.